# Building a class Date, converting a date to a number of days, or a number of days to a valid date

Tags: java

I'm currently training in Java, and I created a class Date that has multiple methods, the ones that i have a problem with (The algorithm isn't right i guess) are the ones that verify dates, convert days to a date, or a date to a day (as shown in the code bellow).

Please I would love to have your input on this.
When i compile the main, that contains a date that I convert to days, then reconvert to a valid date, the problem is it comes back as a different one. So please any ideas or suggestions would be welcome.

Here's the code 
(is now working perfectly, (up until now), was fixed after many trials and errors, so this is the final edit containing the working code)

```
//Main
package Classes;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date d1=new Date(30,12,30,12,2005);
        d1.normalize();
        System.out.print(d1);
        int i=d1.dateToDays();
        System.out.println(" has "+i+" days");
        Date d2=new Date(0,0,i,1,1);
        System.out.println(i+" is the number of days equivalent to "+d2);

    }

}

//Class : Date
package Classes;

public class Date {
        private int min;
        private int hh;
        private int dd;
        private int mm;
        private int yyyy;

        public Date(int min, int hh, int dd, int mm, int yyyy) {
            super();

                this.min = min;
                this.hh = hh;
                this.dd = dd;
                this.mm = mm;
                this.yyyy = yyyy;
                if(verify()==false) normalize();
        }   
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Date [min=" + min + ", hh=" + hh + ", dd=" + dd + ", mm="
                    + mm + ", yyyy=" + yyyy + "]";
        }
        //Method isBefore returns true if actual date is before the one passed as argument
        public boolean isBefore(Date d){
            if(yyyy<d.yyyy)
            {

                return true;
            }
            else if(yyyy==d.yyyy)
            {
                if(mm<d.mm)
                {

                    return true;
                }
                else if(mm==d.mm)
                {
                    if(dd<d.dd)
                    {

                        return true;
                    }
                    else if(hh==d.hh)
                    {
                        if(min<d.min)
                        {

                            return true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;   
            }
            return false;
        }
        //Method isAfter returns true if actual date is after the one passed as argument
        public boolean isAfter(Date d){
            if(isBefore(d)==false && this.identicalTo(d)==false)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        //Method identicalTo returns true if actual date is identical to the one passed as argument
        public boolean identicalTo(Date d){
            if(yyyy==d.yyyy&&mm==d.mm&&dd==d.dd&&hh==d.hh&&min==d.min) return true;
            return false;
        }
        //Method sameDayAs
        public boolean sameDayAs(Date d){
            if(yyyy==d.yyyy&&mm==d.mm&&dd==d.dd) return true;
            return false;
        }
        //Method isLeap, determines if current year it's a leap year (true) or not (false)
        public boolean isLeap() 
        {
            if((yyyy%4==0&&yyyy%100!=0)||yyyy%400==0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        //Method monthType() returns 1 if month has 31 days, 2 if month has 30 days, 3 if month has 28 days, 4 if month has 29 days
        public int monthType(){
            if(mm==1||mm==3||mm==5||mm==7||mm==8||mm==10||mm==12) //For months that contain 31 days
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else if(mm==4||mm==6||mm==9||mm==11) //For months that contain 30 days
            {
                return 2;
            }
            else if(mm==2)
            {
                if(isLeap()==false)//If current year isn't a leap year
                {
                    return 3;//For when Fabruary contains 28 days
                }
                else
                {
                    return 4;//For when Fabruary contains 28 days
                }
            }
            return  0; 
        }
        //Method verify, verifies if the current date is a valid one.
        public boolean verify(){
            if(yyyy>0)
            {
                if(mm<13 && mm>0)
                {
                    if(monthType()==1      && (dd<=31 && dd>=1))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else if(monthType()==2 && (dd<=30 && dd>=1))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else if(monthType()==3 && (dd<=28 && dd>=1))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else if(monthType()==4 && (dd<=29 && dd>=1))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else return false;
                }
                return false;
            }
            return false;

        }
        //Method normalize, Converts a number of days into a dd mm yyyy valid date.
        public void normalize()
        {

            while(verify()==false)
                {
                    if(monthType()==1)
                    {

                        if(dd>31) {
                            dd-=31;
                            mm++;
                        }
                    }
                    else if(monthType()==2)
                    {
                        if(dd>30) {
                            dd-=30;
                            mm++;
                        }
                    }
                    else if(monthType()==3)
                    {
                        if(dd>28) {
                            dd-=28;
                            mm++;
                        }
                    }
                    else if(monthType()==4)
                    {
                        if(dd>29) {
                            dd-=29;
                            mm++;
                        }
                    }

                    if(mm>12)
                    {
                        int temp_yyyy=0;
                        temp_yyyy=mm/12;
                        yyyy+=temp_yyyy;
                        mm%=12;
                    }
                }

        }
        //Converts a valid day into a number of days 
        public int dateToDays(){
            int days=0;

            days+=dd;
            dd=1;
            while(yyyy>1)
            {   
                if(isLeap())
                {
                    days+=366;
                    yyyy--;
                }
                else
                {
                    days+=365;
                    yyyy--;
                }   
            }
            yyyy--;//Because the constructor begins with 1, so the date would have 1 more year than the one equivalent to the number of days entered
            //This first if else if block is used as a first iteration before the while loop that only deals with dd as 31 30 28 or 29 (but not bellow)
            if(monthType()==1){
                days+=(31-dd);
                mm--;
            }
            else if(monthType()==2){
                days+=(30-dd);
                mm--;
            }
            else if(monthType()==3){
                days+=(28-dd);
                mm--;
            }
            else if(monthType()==4){
                days+=(29-dd);
                mm--;
            }
            mm--;//Because the constructor begins with 1, so the date would have 1 more month than the one equivalent to the number of days entered
            while(mm>1)
            {
                if(monthType()==1){
                    days+=31;
                    mm--;
                }
                else if(monthType()==2){
                    days+=30;
                    mm--;
                }
                else if(monthType()==3){
                    days+=28;
                    mm--;
                }
                else if(monthType()==4){
                    days+=29;
                    mm--;
                }
            }
            return days;
        }
}
```

Comment: in the `dateToDays()` method: `dd-=dd;` is the same as `dd = dd - dd;` so `dd = 0;`. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Fixed :P but that doesn't really solve the problem I described up there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that at least your "normalize" method doesn't work correctly.
Imagine you have d=10, then `mm++; if(dd>31) dd-=31; else dd=0;` would lead to d=0. You would loose any days (here 10) that are less than the max. amount of days for that month.

Comment: Oh right idk why I did that. But nonetheless I fixed it but the problem still persists

Comment: if(mm>12){ yyyy++; mm%=12; } is also not correct when you enter mm=36. in this case mm%12 would be 0 and year would only increment by one instead of 3.

Comment: Also in dateToDays you init days=1; shouldn't it be initialized with 0?

Comment: I also recognized, that the testcall you wrote is not consisten. IF your code would return the correct amount of days on d1.dateToDays(), the created new Date d2 as you do with `d2 = new Date(0, 0, i, 1, 1);` would have at least 1 year and 1 month more than the previous date. But calling the constructor with months=0 and years=0 results in an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks! so to fix this issue, i only have to add a yyyy-- in the end of the year loop(outside) , and mm-- in the end (outside) and finally to day i need to leave dd=1 instead of dd=0. :) great idea thanks.


I applied the fix, but there's still one extra year

Comment: And also fixed the issue of mm%=12 :) thanks a bunch, all i need to figure out now is why i get one extra year, like I wrote in the edited text above.

Comment: DONE !! All i had to do was in the condition of daysToDate, the while loops for year and month had a strictly positive condition. Now i turned it into (yyyy>1) and (mm>1) because the date format only begins in month 1 year 1 day 1 :)). Thank you a lot for your answers they inspired me and showed me obvious mistakes aswell :) thanks  a bunch, i would've deffinitely upvoted your reputation but i need 15 rep points to do that :P

Answer (score 0):

As per my analysis you are only working from one side.You are entering the data as a given format and publishing the data as you need. But, you have not implemented the reverse order.You need to add that functionality so that if you pass the number of days, it will give you the expected result.

Hope you will solve it by adding that functionality.

Comment: If i understood your comment, that would be the method daysToDate , we pass the number of days and it gives us the expected result